# How can I resolve this BindException when starting Spring Boot / Vaadin 23 project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

When I start my Vaadin / Spring Boot application from my IDE I get the following Server Error.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
    Can't assign requested address
    java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
        at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.serveDevModeRequest(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:724)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileServer.serveStaticResource(StaticFileServer.java:243)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticOrWebJarRequest(VaadinServlet.java:331)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:286)
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
```

There is nothing listening on the port prior to booting the app.

Running this on Mac OS 12.3.1.

VAADIN 23.0.9

This is so strange I can't even think of what else to include for this to make some sense.

Any ideas?

Thank you!
Kristof

Comment: What is the port number? I think if it's below 1024 the process needs root access to bind.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a Vaadin issue specifically. Are you connected to a VPN or does your hosts file contain something that might be causing trouble?

Comment: @ollitietavainen, no this is all just localhost during development.
Running on port 8080. 


I was doubting if this is Vaadin related or not, but the thing is ... port 8080 is running as I get the error page in my browser. 
And what I see this line in the error. So it looks like Vaadin has an issue to serve the static resources, no?
com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileServer.serveStaticResource(StaticFileServer.java:243) ~[flow-server-23.0.7.jar:23.0.7]


Maybe related to this? https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/12765

Comment: @kristof.taveirne the linked issue is more about the symptom, the uninformative error message, instead of the cause. In that particular ticket, the cause was a malformed template file, which should now report a sensible error message.

Comment: I see in my debugger that AbstractDevServerRunner is trying to connect to localhost port 0. In the constructor this should have started a new dev server, but in the handler the port is still 0, which by then I think should point to the started dev server instance (if I understand correctly).

Comment: This still is an issue, but now I discovered that when I disable security in the app I can clearly see that something is going wrong on Vaadin level.

In my browser I see a rendering of some JSON representing the data endpoint that vaadin would typically use to fetch the data. There is no UI rendering going on at all, looks like the Vaadin part of the application just failed to start.


This is what I see in the browser: 

`{
  "_links" : {
    "workSchedules" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/workSchedules{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }, ...
  }
}`

Comment: I experienced possibly the same issue. If you change your log level to `debug`, you'll notice the server trying to access port `0`. Cleaning up the project and rebuilding the frontend solve it for me.